# RxJs Conditional Debounce and Sampling

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Conditional adding debounce time to a stream based on value from other stream

```
const configuration$ = new Subject().asObservable();
const animation$ = new BehaviorSubject(false).asObservable;
```

the above comes from some service

```
configuration$.pipe(debounceTime(CONSTANTS.DEBOUNCE),sample(interval(CONSTANTS.SAMPLE)));

configuration.subscribe(data=> {
   // do the stuff; 
});
```

If animation$ has true value then `debounceTime`, `sample` should be skipped.

How can I extract value from animation$ and apply if else logic.

If only I can do

```
 configuration$.pipe(
    animation$ ? 
    pipe(debounceTime(CONSTANTS.DEBOUNCE),sample(interval(CONSTANTS.SAMPLE))) :
    of
);
```

Comment: I think what you're asking for is to add `animation$` to the stream before `debounceTime`?

Comment: if animation$ have true value then then ddon't debounce

Comment: Ah I had that backwards. I modified my answer below

Answer (score 2):

```
configuration$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(animation$),
  filter((stream) => !stream[1]),

  // now the rest of the stream will only execute if animation$ emits true
  debounceTime(CONSTANTS.DEBOUNCE),
  sample(interval(CONSTANTS.SAMPLE)),
  map(stream=>stream[0])
);

configuration.subscribe(data=> {
   // do the stuff; 
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i edited the ur answer to use map at end.

Comment: if animation is false then debounce should be applied else skip debounce

Comment: this is not correct, config stream should be debounced based on animation$ stream

Comment: I am not understanding your question then. So
1) `debounceTime` should not execute if `animation$` stream returns false
2) `debounceTime` should execute if `animation$` stream returns true
3) `sample` should always execute 

Am I understanding that that correctly?

Comment: if animation$ is true debounceTime  & sample should not execute, if animation$ is false execute both debounceTime & sample